# Saving emails to MySQL for staff members CRM

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a customer relations system which I have built, what I would like to know is what is the best way to save emails to MySQL so I don't have to create each staff member an actual email address, as we have staff members accessing the CRM and not Outlook.

Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: @Downvoters: please tell us **why** you downvoted? Otherwise how should someone know, what went wrong?

Comment: I have not tried yet to make it, I am trying to get as much information on the right way to make this

Comment: This question is too broad by today's standards, and is also a request for (documentation) resources, which is also off-topic. I will vote to close for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An email in itself already content all the necessary data if you don't forget to record the headers.

You must absolutely keep the full headers, because it will be useful if there is any troubles with the customers. Only the headers are proof.

Of course you will have to add columns in mysql about your personalised data: customer_id, user_id, and whatever your CRM needs.

Other than that, even if they are in the email you can add some mysql columns that might be useful for you CRM: date, subject, user_to, address_from... it all depends on your use of them.

I think I would keep in BLOB the full content of the email since there can be files attached. It could end bigger than 10MB...

Comment: how would i know if there is an attachment and be able to save that in blob to the server or save it to an ftp file

Comment: the content of an email is plain text, following the mime format. Each part adds new data. Certainly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME could explain it better than me.

Answer (score 1):

**Database structure:** This is just some pseudo sql to show you what you could use for your table structure..

```
CREATE table `emails`
id int auto_increment primary_key
email_to varchar 255
email_cc varchar 255
email_bcc varchar 255
email_from varchar 255
email_subject varchar 255
email_message text
customer_id int
user_id int

#use this field to flag the email to be sent
#i use a cron task that sends x emails per x minutes 
#to avoid spam filtering and black listing
email_flag ENUM (0,1) default 0
email_sent_timestamp int
email_created_timestamp int
email_has_attachments ENUM (0,1) default 0

#this will be a serialized field of filenames
#using a naming convention as such: user_id_timestamp.pdf
#that you could use php to split and return. 
#IE: 13_15648461867.pdf;14_5186484834.jpg
email_attachments text
```

**File Uploading:**
i personally wouldn't recommend using mysql to store files, especially if they're quite large. Its much easier to use php and its file interactiosn to upload to a directory until email is sent.

store files in a `chmod 777` folder called `/uploads`

**Example of file upload.** This uploads as a temporary file name and checks if it exists. Google search provided this snippet. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

```
<?php
$target_path = "/uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Store the filename in the database table.. use PHP split and a foreach when sending the email to attach the documents.

```
<?php
$attachments = split(";", $email_attachments);
foreach ($attachments as $a){
    // attachments code here, see php mail()
    // http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#105661
}
//create a script that doesn't have web access 
//to be initiated via cron that connects to the `emails` table
//and retrieves all emails that are email_flag=0
//put them into array, and loop through 10 at a time for every 5 minutes
//send out the email
//set email_flag to 1
?>
```

IF you need actual code samples let me know. And i can throw a working example together.

Comment: it should go without mentioning that you need to perform XSS/HTML_SPECIAL_CHARS filtering on all of the user interactions.. you also should allow specific file types to prevent script executions..

Answer (score 0):

I think the "email" almost mean "post" . So just create mysql table: id, user_id, email_id and save emails in it.